# What condition guarantees that every sequence in a set converges in that set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was wondering whether there exists a set, say $A$ such that every sequence $a_n \in A$ converges to some point in $A$. I found out that any set which contains more than one element cannot satisfy such a criteria, since if {${a_1,a_2}$} be such an $A$, then immediately I can construct a sequence $a_n=a_1,a_2,a_1,a_2,...$ which diverges. Hence I came to a conclusion that a singleton set is the only condition that satisfies such a criteria. Are there any more? If yes, what must be the condition?

Comment: For topological spaces in general, however, it is true for every set $A$ with the following property: if $U$ is an open set, and $U\cap A\ne\varnothing$, then $U\supseteq A$. Then every sequence in $A$ converges to **every** point of $A$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If I consider the real line as my toplogical space, with $(-1,1)$ being $A$(say), how does that guarantee every sequence in $A$ converges in $A$, even though your property is satisfied? Can I not construct an oscillating sequence in $A$? I am actually new to real analysis, so even the smallest help matters. Thanks.

Comment: My property is emphatically **not** satisfied in your example. There are infinitely many open sets in $\Bbb R$ that intersect $(-1,1)$ but do not contain it. A set $A$ has my property if and only if the topology that it inherits from the ambient space is the indiscrete (trivial) topology, and for subsets of $\Bbb R$ that limits $A$ to singletons and the empty set.

Comment: The condition that every sequence from $A$ has *some subsequence* that converges to some $a \in A$, is equivalent to compactness of $A$ in metric spaces. The much stronger condition you propose only works for singletons and the empty set in that setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are writing in the context of metric spaces, the only other possibility is when $A=\emptyset$. In this case, your condition is vacuously true.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the question is trivial in the realm of T1-spaces. However without separation, I think, it's a nice exercise, namely:

Let $X$ be a topological space.
The following are equivalent:

1. Each sequence in $X$ converges.
2. $X$ is ultraconnected (i.e. two non-empty closed subsets have non-empty intersection) and $X$ is countably quasi-compact (i.e. "countably compact without T2").
3. Each countable family of non-empty closed subsets has non-empty intersection or $X$ is empty.

*Proof:*
$\it{1 \Rightarrow 2}$:
$X$ *is ultraconnected:*
Let $A, B$ be non-empty closed subsets of $X$. Pick $a \in A, b \in B$. Then the sequence $a,b,a,b, ...$ converges to some $x$. It is easy to see that $x \in A \cap B$. 
In particular, each sequence has an accumulation point. Therefore, $X$ *is countably quasi-compact*.

$\it{2 \Rightarrow 3}$:
Let $X$ be non-empty and $\mathfrak{F}$ be a countable family of non-empty closed subsets of $X$. By ultraconnectness, $\mathfrak{F}$ has finite intersection property. Hence $\bigcap \mathfrak{F} \neq \emptyset$.

$\it{3 \Rightarrow 1}$:
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $X$.
Then there exists a $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\overline{\{x_n\}}$. It it easily seen that
$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow x$.

*Remarks:*

1. If $X$ contains only finitely many open subsets, in particular, if $X$ is finite, 2. reduces to "$X$ is ultraconnected."
2. For a direct proof of $\it{1 \Rightarrow 3}$
   let $(F_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a countable family of non-empty closed subsets of $X$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ choose an $x_n \in F_n$ and consider the sequence
   $x_1, x_1, x_2, x_1, x_2, x_3, ...$